# React Native - Callback setstate not work properly in iOS

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, setstate

I have a modal component (loader) and used it almost on every screen, but the problem is when I've `setState` and calling `Alert` in `callback setState` it's not work properly,

here's my code:

```
LoginProcess(){
this.setState({postLoader:true})
//calling API and handle if the password is wrong, showing alert
  if(response.ok && response.status == 200){
    //navigate to home
  } else {
    this.setState({postLoader:false},()=>Alert.alert("Perhatian", "Password salah!\nSilahkan coba kembali"))
  }
}

<View>
  <PostLoader showModal={this.state.postLoader} nameLoader="Mengirim data"/> //the loader using modal
</View>
```

as you can see in `else{}` I've handle the `callback` to show `alert`, but the actual result is strange,

[image]

my `postLoader` state is still `true` and the `Alert` popup and close itself, so i can't do anything except swipe my app in `recent apps` and reopen,

anyone has an idea how to wait `postLoader` state to false then call `Alert`?

Comment: Why is ```PostLoader``` managing it's own visibility? What else is it doing?

Comment: @Wainage I just create my own component `Loader`, something i didn't know is the code works in `android` but why not in `iOS`, I'm using `react native` component to create my own `Loader`, like `Modal, Image`, that's why I did what `Modal` do with `visible prop in modal`

Answer (score 0):

May be set the state to false and then show the alert box. When you show the alert in callback of the setState the state will be changed but the component will not re-render itself. Try this,

```
LoginProcess(){
this.setState({postLoader:true})
//calling API and handle if the password is wrong, showing alert
  if(response.ok && response.status == 200){
    //navigate to home
  } else {
    this.setState({postLoader:false})
    Alert.alert("Perhatian", "Password salah!\nSilahkan coba kembali")
  }
}

<View>
  <PostLoader showModal={this.state.postLoader} nameLoader="Mengirim data"/> //the loader using modal
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout that will be executed after the this.setState after the specified ms(milliseconds) and will work as needed.

```
LoginProcess(){
this.setState({postLoader:true})
//calling API and handle if the password is wrong, showing alert
  if(response.ok && response.status == 200){
    //navigate to home
  } else {
    this.setState({postLoader:false})
    setTimeout(() => {
    Alert.alert("Perhatian", "Password salah!\nSilahkan coba kembali")
    }, 100);
  }
}

<View>
  <PostLoader showModal={this.state.postLoader} nameLoader="Mengirim data"/> //the loader using modal
</View>
```